# Stack/Merge two svg images in php

Tags: php, svg

Is there a way in php to add two svg images into one svg

Something like it's done with python in https://github.com/astraw/svg_stack

imagecopyresampled can not output to svg.
Imagemagick convert / montage seem also only for bitmaps

---

About the remark "is not really common need for web developers"
My specific need is to create a downloadable svg composed of a generated QR and a vector logo.
When you need to show layered svg on a webpage, it could be easier using a javascript/html/css solution.

---

**SOLUTION**
Altought the question was closed because it was flagged as "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for software libraries"
I am posting my solution, hoping the answer can help some other lost soul ;).

I found this package https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg and used the following code:

```
//load qr code from file
$fileContent = SVG::fromFile('qr.svg');
$doc = $fileContent->getDocument();
//select logo from svg, scale and move it to the right position 
$logo = SVG::fromFile('logo.svg')->getDocument();
$logo->getChild(0)->setAttribute('transform', "translate(73 10) scale(1.29)");
$doc->addChild($logo);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=videoQR.svg");
exit($fileContent);
```

Comment: ImageMagick is a raster processor, not vector. It will rasterize the two SVG files before stacking them. The SVG rasterizing is done with Inkscape or RSVG or IM internal MSVG renderers depending on your configuration. `convert svg1 svg2 -append result.png`  You cannot save the result as an SVG file unless you have a raster to vector processor such as potrace available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fine answer by ImageMagick expert above (fmw42). I quickly checked your Python script referenced and it appears it just adds two SVGs files one below another.

You can just do the similar merging with PHP. The method to use may vary based on what you need. The easiest way would be to define new SVG as a string variable with only  tag, add the contents of both files and end your wrapping SVG with the ending  tag. This works because SVG files can be embedded into other SVG files.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. SVG is like XML. 
You can copy the second image. Remove the parent tags and add it to the parent of the first image?
That sounds trivial and it's strange there is not some package for that in php.

Comment: Yes, as you described. The challenge might be matching the dimensions (at least width) of merged images, possibly overlaying them etc.

So either way you'll have to do some attribute gathering (SVG root element, width and height attributes or viewBox attribute) and adjusting them in the output SVG.

Regarding the package in the PHP repository etc this operation is not really common need for web developers, don't you think? If needed it can be scripted relatively easy while for web animations you usually script them to animate objects in (the same) SVG file.

Comment: Wanted te report back, that I found a solution, but somebody closed this.. 
By using https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg
And the following code

use SVG\SVG;
use SVG\Nodes\Shapes\SVGRect;

$image = SVG::fromFile('qr.svg');
$doc = $image->getDocument();

$file = SVG::fromFile('logo.svg');
$doc2 = $file->getDocument();
$doc->addChild($doc2);

echo $image;

Comment: Sure, with any SVG library (or with plain javascript scripting DOM) it should be possible to do what you did. To really match two images you should add additional scripting as I've described in the comment above.